# Castle Facilities NHibernateIntegration vs Castle Facilities NHibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, castle-windsor

Can anybody shed some light on the difference of these two?
I want to use fluent Nhibernate which the second facility provides support for. But I also want to use the http module (SessionWebModule) for open session in view support which seems to reside in the first facility. Are they compatible, should I use both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the creator of NHibernate Facility and the committer on Castle.Transactions. (not participating in NHibernate Integration facility)

I created the NHibernate facility as a Windsor-facility-only type of project. It works mostly around the concept *session per transaction* and not *session per request*. However, to the c'tor of the NHibernateFacility you can pass an enum that makes the default lifestyle *session per request*.

They are not compatible as you can see from the version numbers. The NHibernate Facility is brand new (but in production, because it's very very tiny). NHibernate Integration on the other hand is the official product.

NHibernate Facility requires you to use Transactions 3.0 which is beta at the moment. The tx support is fully there, but not the transactional NTFS bits.

I use my own NHibernate Facility for my own projects and it works really well. YMMV.

Comment: It looks great (the Nhibernate Facility that is). I have it up and running, will look in to your tip tomorrow

Comment: BTW Is there anything else needed to be done to get session per request running? Like maybe starting a transaction using a http module?

Comment: Just pass the correct enum value to the NHibernateFacility c'tor. The transactions will flush the ISession.

Comment: The difference between "Facilities NHibernateIntegration" & "Castle Facilities NHibernate" sounds rather like the difference between the People's Front of Judea and the Judean People's Front

Comment: Yup :) My opinion is that they trash NHibernateIntegration, because I'm at feature-parity with much smaller LOC footprint.

Comment: Ah right, I didn't realize they were feature-parity and I'm now having problems with NibernateIntegration's nuget dependencies, so looks like I should take this opportunity to try and switch. I just basically use the [Transaction] attribute feature.

Comment: Very odd, but implementing with ...            _container.AddFacility<AutoTxFacility>()
                      .Register(Component.For<INHibernateInstaller>().ImplementedBy<ExampleInstaller>())
                      .AddFacility<NHibernateFacility>(
                          f => f.DefaultLifeStyle = DefaultSessionLifeStyleOption.SessionPerWebRequest); ... and configuring the HttpModule, changes aren't persisted unless explicitly flushed...

Comment: Oh, the calling method must be marked with [Transaction]. I wrongly assumed that some internal PerWebRequest magic was taking care of that.

Comment: Yes, and you need to be aware of where you put that attribute, because the facility is designed for *one* transaction for a business operation; don't have nested calls to [Transaction].